# Server-Side Form Handling And Retrieving Server Responses On The Client-Side

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, server-side-scripting

I'm making a website and I need to submit user input for login through a form to a Google Apps Script. I know how to submit the form. My problem is that I don't know how to handle forms with Google Apps Script. I am using the doPost() method. I know how to manipulate the form data but not how to retrieve it. **How do I retrieve my form data in Google Apps Script?** and **What would I put in the return statement of my doPost() function if I just want to return a boolean variable to my website that says whether or not the user input is valid?** (I assume I would just return a boolean variable but I just want to make sure that it doesn't work differently with Google Apps Script server-side form handling.) and **After I return that boolean variable to my website, how do I program the client-side to retrieve the response from my Google Apps Script so I can process that response with javascript?**

Comment: Please provide some code for a specifc question.

Comment: @ViperCode I don't have any code yet, you also shouldn't need any to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `doPost()` and `doGet()` can get URL search string parameters.

```
function doGet(e) {

  var passedInIP = e.parameter.theArg;
  var listInfo = e.parameter.List;

  //Other code
};
```

The url would look like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/theAppsScriptID/exec?theArg=theIP_Address&List=textHereForList
```

The name in the URL must match up with the named used in `e.parameter.nameHere`